# Dynamically add properties to this.state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm running a map that dynamically creates a group of components where the total number is based on the length of an array.  Each component needs its own value in state.

So if the map runs over an array of three items...

```
arr.map((item, index) => {
  const newStateProp = "item" + index;
  return newStateProp;
}
```

The app state would look like this somewhere...maybe similar to what you would see in React Dev Tools...

```
...
this.state: {
  item0: false,
  item1: false,
  item2: false
}
...
```

Not sure if this is doable...thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you not store them in an array?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you saying create an array on the fly, and then add it to state with setState?

Comment: You have an array already, why do you need another one?

Comment: The array contains elements that need to be manipulated to a certain text string,an then adds them as keys to an object in state.  The loop above takes the array items and them dumps them into an object with a value, false in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
newState = {};

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newState[arr[i]] = false
}

setState(newState);
```

Is that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, It is possible to do like that.

If you want to do something like that after `component` is mounted, you can refer to [Chris Sandvik Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55232291/3568000).

But If you want to do it in constructor using from props or anything else. You can do some change to his code like below.

```js
const arr = [];
const newState = {};

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newState[`item${arr[i]}`] = false;
}

this.state = newState;

console.log('State', this.state);
```